# How to deal with skewed data?

Tags: distributions, correlation, inference, normality-assumption, skew-normal-distribution

I want to examine 2 variables of experience:
A. Regular practice - hours.
B. Formal practice - days.

Both variables are right-skewed, with extreme outliers (Experts) and many subjects with zero experience (none experience).
I want to calculate Pearson correlation between these 2 variables and others variables in my study and use the experience as a covariate in other analyses (e.g., mixed design Anova), and for that purposes I need to transform the experience variable into a normal distribution.

My questions are:

1. How can I choose the best transformation?
2. whether I choose log10 transform, how should I relate to zero values? (log(0) is undefined of course)

Here is my 2 variables (line = subject in my study)

```
Formal_Pactice_Days Regualr_Practice_Hours
16  0
51  1278.347695
6   108.7030353
4   286.9760131
14  34.78497128
12  43.4812141
415 1695.76735
27  86.9624282
12  486.9895979
9   21.74060705
8   456.5527481
18  166.53305
9   75.36743777
3   1154.426234
6   71.01931636
10  23.18998085
55  973.9791958
21  104.3549138
9   17.39248564
100 784.8359145
19  456.5527481
2   139.1398851
2   108.7030353
12  113.0511567
8   217.4060705
12  152.1842494
15  26.08872846
38  72.46869017
44  52.17745692
44  208.7098277
20  17.39248564
0   256.5391632
37  234.7985561
18  195.6654635
15  29.34981952
3   0
11  517.4264478
14  28.26278917
12  43.4812141
5   195.6654635
5   45.65527481
0   104.3549138
3   391.3309269
0   24.92922942
9   78.26618538
0   6.522182115
10  12.68202078
15  15.21842494
23  10.87030353
42  352.1978342
15  113.0511567
34  231.320059
2   10.87030353
0   478.2933551
92  2556.695389
0   78.26618538
5   365.2421984
0   45.65527481
24  53.48189334
0   34.78497128
0   43.4812141
0   304.3684987
0   4.34812141
0   23.18998085
0   31.88622367
2   631.3472287
0   19.56654635
2   27.17575881
0   19.56654635
30  469.5971123
10  195.6654635
20  626.129483
3   260.8872846
0   4.34812141
0   260.8872846
144 1199.356822
10  17.39248564
0   0
21  0
86  2754.969725
2   17.39248564
0   13.04436423
0   307.9919332
0   34.78497128
12  71.74400327
72  410.8974732
32  273.9316488
13  199.288898
21  2791.493945
1   88.411802
10  0
19  626.129483
19  13.04436423
0   17.39248564
22  133.7047334
2   0
0   39.13309269
0   139.1398851
41  173.9248564
22  83.04911893
12  25.36404156
531 5843.875175
0   273.9316488
0   83.48393107
43  285.5266393
2   0
15  589.895138
0   17.39248564
0   156.5323708
9   52.17745692
26  69.56994256
15  109.4277222
0   88.04945855
0   0
0   36.52421984
0   0
64  130.4436423
66  1826.210992
0   8.69624282
0   6.522182115
0   46.37996171
0   434.812141
2   41.74196554
0   315.2388022
20  26.08872846
0   2.174060705
0   26.08872846
193 2391.466776
1   19.56654635
26  17.39248564
0   104.3549138
2   10.87030353
16  391.3309269
0   17.39248564
47  695.6994256
0   30.43684987
8   313.0647415
2   0
0   14.49373803
10  52.17745692
0   88.70167676
0   16.30545529
45  1512.711439
0   0
0   0
0   6.522182115
14  173.9248564
0   217.4060705
```

---

[image]

`SpearmanrResult(correlation=0.45627434628406804, pvalue=5.607188590282884e-09)`

Comment: Why do you need normal distributions?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the Pearson correlation coefficient on variables A and B, or on the transformed variables A and B? If you are interested in extending inferences about correlation on the transformed variables back to the untransformed variables, you might consider using **Spearman's *rank* correlation coefficient**,  which essentially uses a ranking transformation, and then calculates Pearson's $r$ on the ranks. This would allow you to draw conclusions like "Group A tends to increase as group B increases."

Comment: Square roots,, cube roots and log(1 + whatever) are all defined for zeros.